# syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in php

Tags: php

Hi I am getting this error and it has become a headache for me. Can anyone please help me where I have committed mistake.

Here is my code.

```
<?php echo mxp_draw_pull_down_menu('datefield', MxpStatistics::getFieldsDropDown(), isset($_SESSION['statistics']['datefield']) ? $_SESSION['statistics']['datefield'] : ' ', 'onchange="javascript: saveModify(document.searchreport'.$rand.', \''.mxp_href_link_admin(FILENAME_DEFAULT, $MxpTemplate->getModule() . '&module=' . substr($file['name'], 0, strrpos($file['name'], '.'))) ."' , null, " . $_GET['windowId']);"');?>
```

Comment: Stop using the ternary operator...

Comment: you're not concatenating correctly (I suppose, this code looks like a big mess)

Comment: The ternary operator is not meant as a substitute for long nested `if-else` statements. [The manual warns you](http://php.net/ternary#language.operators.comparison.ternary): "*It is recommended that you avoid "stacking" ternary expressions. PHP's behaviour when using more than one ternary operator within a single statement is non-obvious.*".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove last four characters(`"');`) from your code.

You can detect you syntax errors easily, if you use any syntax highlighting IDE.
Also, if you try to save number of line like this, it will be a real headache for you to find syntax errors and debug.

Try this code

```
<?php 
echo mxp_draw_pull_down_menu('datefield', MxpStatistics::getFieldsDropDown(), isset($_SESSION['statistics']['datefield']) ? $_SESSION['statistics']['datefield'] : ' ', 'onchange="javascript: saveModify(document.searchreport'.$rand.', \''.mxp_href_link_admin(FILENAME_DEFAULT, $MxpTemplate->getModule() . '&module=' . substr($file['name'], 0, strrpos($file['name'], '.'))) ."' , null, " . $_GET['windowId']);
?>
```